# Generate .env.yaml from bitbucket pipelines

Tags: google-cloud-functions, yaml, environment-variables, bitbucket

I'm trying to create a bitbucket pipeline step that could generate a .env.yaml to set the env variables for the Google Cloud - Cloud Functions I'm deploying from this pipeline.

at the moment I generate the file like this:

```
          - echo AIRTABLE_API_KEY:\ "${AIRTABLE_API_KEY}" > .env.yaml
          - echo AIRTABLE_BASE_ID:\ "${AIRTABLE_BASE_ID}" >> .env.yaml
```

I don't want to copy every env var here, but I have 20-30 env vars for these functions, and it's not too elegant to specify every variable name in my script. I'm looking for a more universal solution, that doesn't require me to edit the script every time, a new variable is needed.
I know that I can use `printenv` command to generate a .env file containing every env variable in the pipeline that uses the `VAR=VALUE` format.

I'm looking for a simple way to transform this .env format to .env.yaml format `VAR: "VALUE"` in a single linux command to generate .env.yaml.

Thanks for any help.

Edit:
Found an npm package that could be usefull, but I'm looking for a simple console command instead of this:
https://github.com/mathieu-bour/dotenv-to-yaml#specifying-source-and-destination

Edit2:

```
printenv | sed 's/=/: "/' | sed 's/$/"/' > ./.env.yaml
```

This seems to do the trick, but I'm getting an error message, because printenv adds bitbucket's own environment variables to the file.

```
ERROR: (gcloud.functions.deploy) ResponseError: status=[400], code=[Ok], message=[The request has errors
Problems:
environment_variables:
environment variable name HOME is reserved by the system: it cannot be set by users
environment variable name PATH is reserved by the system: it cannot be set by users
environment variable name PWD is reserved by the system: it cannot be set by users
environment variable name SHLVL is reserved by the system: it cannot be set by users
environment variable name _ is reserved by the system: it cannot be set by users
```